# How to log certain message to a logfile when my cronjob ran?

Tags: cron

I try to write the message "Ran Cronjob XY" to a logfile if my cronjob ran.

**Attempt:**

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php /home/company/example.de/bin/magento list 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran Cronjob XY" >> /home/company/example.de/var/log/test.cron.log
```

But this fails and logs the output of the command `/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php /home/company/example.de/bin/magento list` instead of just **Ran Cronjob XY**

**Bonus:**

Show how to print "ran successfully" if the command was executed successfully and "failed" if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```bsh
if some_command >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo ran successfully
else
    echo failed
fi >>logfile
```

The above code will run the command `some_command`, discard its output, and then append the text `ran successfully` to the file `logfile` if the command finished successfully.  If the command fails, it would append the text `failed` to `logfile`.

In your case, for simplicity (since you have so long pathnames in your commands), I would put this in its own wrapper script and execute *that* script with a cron job.

The script would look like

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin:$PATH

logfile=/home/company/example.de/var/log/test.cron.log

if php /home/company/example.de/bin/magento list >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo ran successfully
else
    echo failed
fi >>"$logfile"
```

I modify `PATH` in the script to allow running `php` without an absolute path.

That script would then be scheduled:

```bsh
* * * * * /path/to/thescript.sh
```

... where the `* * * * *` should be replaced by the actual schedule.

If you'd wanted to turn this into a "one-liner" for use directly in a crontab entry:

```bsh
* * * * * if /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php /home/company/example.de/bin/magento list >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo ran successfully; else echo failed; fi >>/home/company/example.de/var/log/test.cron.log
```

... where the `* * * * *` should be replaced by the actual schedule.

Comment: Might be simpler to just write as `* * * * *  (/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php ... && echo "worked" || echo "failed") > logfile`.

Comment: @terdon Should we replace `...` with `/home/company/example.de/bin/magento list` or with `/home/company/example.de/bin/magento list >/dev/null 2>&1` in your example?

Comment: @Black I was thinking of this: `* * * * * ( /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php /home/company/example.de/bin/magento list >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo ran successfully || echo failed ) >>/home/company/example.de/var/log/test.cron.log`. But note that this is just a question of syntax, that does exactly the same thing as Kusalananda's version, and his version is clearer and easier to understand. Mine is just a little bit shorter.

Comment: @terdon Yours would work, but lists with `&&` and `||` doesn't follow the same clear semantics as the slightly more verbose `if ...; then ...; else ...; fi`, and it's easy to get it wrong when trying to generalise it.  The two are simply not equivalent.  For example, `echo failed` would run if _either_ of the preceding two commands failed.

Comment: @Kusalananda you mean if the `echo "ran successfully"` failed? True, unlikely, but yes very true.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to want to echo a message to the log file if the first command ran successfully. In that case, you can use a double ampersand `&&` instead of a pipe `|`:
`/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php /home/company/example.de/bin/magento list 2>&1 && echo "Ran Cronjob XY" >> /home/company/example.de/var/log/test.cron.log`

Comment: please use `>/dev/null 2>&1` instead of just `2>&1` in your answer because the command output is not needed.

Comment: This will just call the first command and then the next, independently if the first command run successfully or not. So how is this a difference from my version?

Comment: No @Black, it will not executed independently. `&&` is logical `AND`. the second command will executed if the first is successful. have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30508672/5217119.

Comment: @summertime, and how can I log if the command was not running successfull?

Comment: @Black You can't affirm your cron job ran your way (the '| echo' way) : put anything that doesn't exist before your pipe, nothing will run, but the echo will write. Test it with "thisisnotacommand | echo "Ran Cronjob XY" >> /home/company/example.de/var/log/test.cron.log"

Comment: @user4089, so If I can't affirm, then how is this different from my version?

Comment: @Black I talk about your version : "I changed grep -v with echo"

Comment: @Black The answer by Kusalananda shows how you can write a simple if/else statement to log success or failure.